# Passing two anonymous objects as parameters in C# wont equate properly. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#

I'm using a function that returns whether two values are equal/not equal. It takes in two anonymous objects and returns a string based on whether they're equal or not. When I pass two equal integers, such as "2" and "2", the function equates them as not equal.

```
public string Assert(bool equals, object obj1, object obj2)
        {
            bool areEqual = (obj1 == obj2);

            if (equals == areEqual)
            {
                return "\n\nSuccess!\n\n";
            }
            return "\n\nFailure!\n\n";
        }
```

If I call `Assert(true, 2, 2)`, the output should be `"Success!"`.
If I call `Assert(false, 2, 2)`, the output should be `"Failure!"`.

However, upon further inspection, `(obj1 == obj2)` returns false when I've passed the integer "2" for both obj1 and obj2. Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

Comment: You've boxed your integers, and you're now checking for referential equality, and two different boxes have two different references.

Comment: You cannot compare the values of two `object` types with `==`. Use `.Equals()` and/or check if `IEquatable` is implemented first.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting this result is that you are boxing the integers to `object` type, and `object` types use the object reference to determine equality (and this would not happen for boxed objects) using the `==` operator.

One way to resolve this issue would be to make your method generic (which takes in any type), and then use the `Equals` method of the type itself (which for integers would be a comparison of the values). By making the method generic, you also remove the unnecessary boxing operation:

```
public static string Assert<T>(bool equals, T obj1, T obj2)
{
    bool areEqual = obj1.Equals(obj2);

    if (equals == areEqual)
    {
        return "\n\nSuccess!\n\n";
    }

    return "\n\nFailure!\n\n";
}
```

Now, there still may be some issues if `T` is a nullable type and `obj1` is `null`, because we'll get a `NullReferenceException` if we try to call `Equals` on a `null` object.

To get around this, we might do a couple of things:

1. Check for `ReferenceEquals` first, which will return `true` if both arguments are `null`. This will also short-circuit the need to call `Equals` if two references to the same object are passed in.
2. Check if `obj1` is not `null` before calling its `Equals` method

For example:

```
public static string Assert<T>(bool equals, T obj1, T obj2)
{
    bool areEqual = false;

    if (ReferenceEquals(obj1, obj2))
    {
        areEqual = true;
    }
    else if (obj1 != null)
    {
        areEqual = obj1.Equals(obj2);
    }

    if (equals == areEqual)
    {
        return "\n\nSuccess!\n\n";
    }

    return "\n\nFailure!\n\n";
}
```

Now if we want to, we can shorten the code using conditional `||` and `&&` operators and the `?:` ternary operator:

```
public static string Assert<T>(bool equals, T obj1, T obj2)
{
    bool areEqual = ReferenceEquals(obj1, obj2) || obj1 != null && obj1.Equals(obj2);

    return equals == areEqual
        ? "\n\nSuccess!\n\n"
        : "\n\nFailure!\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Seems like an excellent answer to me.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Equals` and make sure to handle nulls

```
public static string Assert(bool equals, object obj1, object obj2)
{
    bool areEqual = obj1 == null && obj2 == null || obj1 != null && obj1.Equals(obj2);
    return equals == areEqual
        ? "\n\nSuccess!\n\n"
        : "\n\nFailure!\n\n";
}
```

`Equals` will be the overridden version of the runtime type of the objects, not the static type.

Note that the `==` operator might be overridden (e.g. in `string`). But the static type is used at compile-time to determine which version will be used. But for the `Equals` method, the run-time type will be used.
Let's make a test

```
string s = "hallo";
string a = "hal";
string b = "lo";

// Constructed, so that we will get the same string value as `s`, but a different reference.
string t = a + b;

object o1 = s;
object o2 = t;
Console.WriteLine(s == t);   // ==> True
Console.WriteLine(o1 == o2); // ==> False
Console.WriteLine(s.Equals(t));   // ==> True
Console.WriteLine(o1.Equals(o2)); // ==> True
```